# Reverse proxy with multiple upstreams

Tags: mitmproxy, libmproxy

I've set up a virtual machine to redirect port 80 connections to some servers to my mitmproxy instance.

Now I wish to set up mitmproxy (or libmproxy) to modify and forward requests to a server of my choosing, depending on the HTTP `Host` header (and also modify responses). How do I accomplish this? Transparent proxy seems to read off the intended target server from the lower network layers, and I don't have that (the VM connects straight to my proxy).

Answer (score 0):

For the current version (0.12.1), you can use https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/dns_spoofing.py

The next release should ship with a dedicated `--spoof` switch.